# document.createElement is not working for anchor tags

Tags: javascript, dom, anchor

I was trying to validate some URLs. I have tried using regex and JavaScript URL constructors as well. But I was specifically trying to solve the task with `document.createElement('a')`.
I am following the codes for the task and it works fine in **JSbin**. But not working in my local editor. Can anyone explain if `document.createElement('a')` is valid for anchor tags and why there is a result in JSbin and not in my local editor(it shows some error).

P.S Working new with JavaSCript and DOM Manipulation

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div"></div>
<script src="test.js"></script
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function isValidURL(str) {
   var div = document.getElementById('div');
   var a  = document.createElement('a');
   a.href = str;
   a.innerText = "check";
   div.appendChild(a);
   return a.protocol === "http:" || a.protocol === "https:";
}
console.log(isValidURL('file:///Y:/bleh/index.html'));
console.log(isValidURL('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFP-EWO_Q_o'));
console.log(isValidURL('en.wikipedia.org'));
```

The console results *false*, *true*, *true* accordingly in *jsbin*. But show error `ReferenceError: document is not defined` in local editor.

Comment: What "local editor" are you using? You might need to set it in a mode for web development since `document` isn't defined in a node environment

Comment: Hi, @Samathingamajig I am using Visual Studio Code. Can you explain the procedure for setting the mode

Comment: That's weird, in VS Code it works perfectly fine. Are you seeing squiggle type things under the word `document` or are you seeing an error if you click the run button? If you're seeing errors from the run button, you shouldn't be using the run button at all, just open the html in your browser (remember to import in the javascript file in the html file)

Comment: The code is perfectly fine. You can just save the HTML and open it in the browser and you should not see this error.

Comment: Thank you @Samathingamajig. Yes, I was clicking the run button for answers. I previewed it in the browser and it works fine.